# Correct way to override save action in controller extensions

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller

Is it ok to call

```
standardController.save();
```

in a controller extension or should one always just do the custom stuff and then do a DML like

```
upsert record;
```

I have the feeling that calling the standard save() from my custom save() behaves strangely under certain circumstances.

What is the right way to do it?

Comment: What are the certain circumstances? I've certainly used standardCtl.save() in a custom controller several times in the past, although honestly there doesn't seem to be much value in doing this. These days I manage the save myself and the only thing I delegate to the standardController is the cancel action.

Comment: I closed this question and replaced it with that one http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/10898/do-i-have-to-prevent-dirty-updates-myself-when-overriding-save-in-a-controller-e